# Samsung S4 and Kies error

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-kies

I am trying to connect my Samsung galaxy S4 to Samsung Kies, yet it says it is not compatible and to download Kies 3 - which I did and then it says the device isn't supported - so both versions of Kies won't work - any ideas its driving me mad :( I have uninstalled and re-installed several times.

thank you

Comment: download the other version of kies at http://www.samsung.com/au/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/

Answer (score 0):

Is the phone in Odin download mode? If you connect the phone when it's in Odin mode, Kies detects it, but gives you exactly those messages. You can't use Kies with Odin, it only works when the device is booted. To use Odin, you need the [Odin desktop app for Windows](http://odindownload.com/).